# Civi Event discount

Tags: civievent, cividiscount

I need to use a discount that is activated when the person registering for an event checks a box on the registration form. How do I connect the checkbox on the form with the discount?

Comment: Are you meaning the standard Civi event registration forms, or some other form?

Comment: A standard Civi event registration form.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar using a custom template (.extra) and some jQuery. Here is how it worked:

- Created a custom field which is the trigger, in our case "are you a member"
- Setup a price field in a price set that has line items for the regular pricing and the discount pricing.
- Use jQuery to hide the price set initially.
- When user selects an option in the custom field it triggers the jQuery which shows the price set and the rows of the price field that are appropriate to the selection. So in our case if they select that they are a member it shows only member pricing if the select that they are not a member it shows only non member pricing.

This scenarios was created for an organization that didn't want to have members login to get the member discount so this put them on the honor system. We have used this method with various similar scenarios.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This sounds like just what I need.....now to figure out the details. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this is possible with some custom code addition in an extension.

You might try adding two similar events with read-only checkboxes -

- On one event, this checkbox will be enabled by default. Add discount to this event page only.
- Second event will have this checkbox disabled by default. No discount added to this page.